# Trying to write file to my working directory: Error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a program to consolidate two lists together, remove duplicates, and write the results to my (working directory). But I get the following error:

```
File "/opt/subdomain-hunter/src/enumerate.py", line 59, in enumerate
    with open(MASTERLIST, "w") as f:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Here is my last few lines of code:

```
# Read both text files and join them together
if os.path.exists('list1.txt'):
    with open('list1.txt') as f:
        list1 = f.read().splitlines()
        f.close()

if os.path.exists('list2.txt'):
    with open('list2.txt') as f:
        list2 = f.read().splitlines()
        f.close()

# Combine these into a MASTERLIST
MASTERLIST = list1 + list2

# Remove duplicates
MASTERLIST = list(set(MASTERLIST))
print('\n\n[+] MASTERLIST created!\n')
with open(MASTERLIST, "w") as f:
    f.write('../conf/ignore.txt')
```

Comment: Your error and code don't match.  The error is referencing `MASTERLIST`, but your code is opening `filename` at the end.

Comment: Sorry, my code has been updated. I did a with open(MASTERLIST, "w") which was originally intended. I still don't have a solution though..

Answer (score 0):

According to your traceback, you're actually calling `open` with the list `MASTERLIST`, rather than `filename` as shown in your posted code. A list is not a valid argument for `open`. You should call `open` with a file name instead and then write the content of `MASTERLIST` to the file object:

```
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(MASTERLIST))
```